# Excel to UTF-8 encoded CSV

Tags: convert

How can one convert an Excel file into a UTF-8 encoded CSV?

Comment: UTF-8 is not a format and txt is not a character encoding. It's entirely possible to have a plain-text file that is encoded as UTF-8. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: just i want to convert Excel to csv with UTF-8 format, please send apex code.

Comment: yes I want to this information "  It's entirely possible to have a plain-text file that is encoded as UTF-8 "

Comment: You mention Apex code in your comment. Are you trying to get the file changed into this format so you can use the Data Loader?

Answer (score 4):

Encode the String with UTF-8 format and Decode the same sting with UTF-8 format.
For example:

```
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('test 123', 'UTF-8');
system.debug(':::encoded::::'+encoded);
String decoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(encoded,'UTF-8');
system.debug(':::decoded::::'+decoded);
```